# python convert time to utc time?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a `date_object.time()`,it's `Asia/Taipei` time

```
date_object.time() = '10:00:00'
```

And I get the  `datetime.datetime.now` with timezone `Asia/Taipei`

```
current = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
taipeitime = current.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei'))
```

And then I combine the `date_object.time()` and `taipeitime`

```
combine = datetime.datetime.combine(taipeitime, date_object.time()) #Asia/Taipei time
```

And I have to convert the `combine` to UTC time
But I get error:

```
print combine.astimezone(pytz.utc)
ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

Please teach me how to convert this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .time() method for datetime looses the timezone info, use .timetz() instead eg:

```
>> combine = datetime.datetime.combine(taipeitime, taipeitime.timetz())
>> combine.astimezone(pytz.utc)

datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 16, 15, 13, 46, 948201, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

vs

```
>> combine = datetime.datetime.combine(taipeitime, taipeitime.time())
>> combine.astimezone(pytz.utc)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetz.

Also you can replace the timezone into the time object, e.g.

```
combine = datetime.datetime.combine(taipeitime,
                   taipeitime.time().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei')))
```

will get you a timezone aware combine time. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.replace